# Error in socket.io of node

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

i have used the following code in express + socket.io

```
app.io.route('customers', {
    create: function (req) {
        console.log("create");
    },
    update: function (req) {
        console.log("update");
    },
    remove: function (req) {
        console.log("remove");
    },
});
```

and I am getting the error as
cannot find method 'route' of undefined

I have used the following:
var express=require('express.io');
var app = require('express.io')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

Does any body know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that `app.io` is undefined, probably because you did not import it properly. To work with `socket.io` you have to import it and make it listen on your server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

});
```

However, I suspect you are using [express.io](http://express-io.org/), and as per their documentation you should do:

```
app = require('express.io')();
app.http().io();

app.io.route('customers', ...);
```